# Loosing column names converting back to dataframe from list

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a dataframe,i need to do two operations:

1. Converting to a list
2. converting the same list back to the dataframe with original column names.

Issue: i am loosing the column names when i first convert to a list and when i convert back to dataframe i am not getting those column names

Please help!

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

#convert df to list
a=df.values.tolist()

#convert back to original dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df1)
```

**Current output**

[image: Current output without column names]

i am unable to get column names

Comment: I am curious why do you need to convert to list and then back to dataframe?

Comment: because i have a appending operation so they say when we append as a list its cost effective than appending to dataframe directly

Comment: Is its possible to use like `a=df.values.tolist()` and `b = df.columns.tolist()` and lastly go back to new dataframe from reserved list values `df2 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = b)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need pass columns names by `df.columns`, also if not default index is necessary pass it too:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

If default `RangeIndex` in original `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=df.columns)
```

EDIT:

If need some similar structure use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='split'` there are converted `DataFrame` to dictionary of columnsnames, index and data like:

```
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

d = df.to_dict(orient='split')
print (d)
{'index': [0, 1, 2],
 'columns': ['Name', 'Age'], 
 'data': [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]}
```

And for original DataFrame use:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d['data'], index=d['index'], columns=d['columns'])
print (df2)
   Name  Age
0   tom   10
1  nick   15
2  juli   14
```

Comment: do i have option to store somewhere inside list without referring df column names?

Comment: @prog - Is possible use dict of lists? Like `df.to_dict(oriet='list')` ?

Comment: @prog, i think you can also keep your column names handy in a list like `b = df.columns.tolist()` and then its simple `df2 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = b)`